# How to add favicon in patternfly-react

Tags: patternfly

I'm trying to use patternfly-react for UI.
I'm not sure how to add my favicon, normally in react we use

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/path/to/favicon.png">
```

But in patternfly-react we don't have any public folder and index.html is in src.

I tried `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">` as my index.html file and favicon is in same folder i.e `/src`.

Here are the screenshots of my tree and index.html

[image: Tree structure]

[image: Index.html]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: My project is based on this [repo](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-react-seed)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this problem.

Posting solution here just in case anyone having the same issue in the future.

Updated my webpack

```
plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html'),
        favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'favicon.ico'),
      })
    ]
```

Added this favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'favicon.ico'), line in my webpack.common.js
favicon.ico is in /src folder.

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

The [Patternfly react seed project](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-react-seed/blob/c612b7b05a254cbc0d86c4586d3a36bd20f74e37/webpack.common.js#L126) solved this in a similar way that you did but they added a new plugin (CopyPlugin) to webpack instead of piggy-backing onto the HtmlWebpackPlugin